# Unwrap model with UVs at proper size?

Tags: uv

I have the model of house with seams on it.
[image: model with seams marked]
When I'm trying to unwrap it (<kbd>U</kbd> > unwrap) It unwraps wrong. 
[image: messed up UVs]
Some polygons are bigger then others, and I don't know what to do.
How do I unwrap it proportional?

Comment: the easy way (but with less control) is to use some automatic unwrap method (cube projection, smart unwrap or lightmap) in the U menu. Learning more about UV mapping could help you in the future : http://cgcookie.com/blender/2011/01/21/intro_uvmapping/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this happens because either :

- have edited the mash after unwrapping
- have scaled the object after unwrapping

to resolve this :

- apply scale :  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select scale
- unwrap the mesh again

Comment: I don't thionk he unwrapped rright in the first place. that's the problem.

Comment: @ARadish he seems to be using seams ,so i think he knows how to unwrap

Comment: notice that he has a seam on every edge? if he was to doo smart UV project, he'd get proportional, but it would be a mess. My guess is the thought process went like this. "Hmmm... unwrap it like a teddy bear... (that's how I learned.) Well, this doesn't even look like a teddy bear. so I guess I can [A] > [Ctrl]+[E] > mark seam. hey! there we go!