# How to effectively UV unwrap a subdivided mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, modifiers

Are problems usual to arise in unwrapping a subsurfed mesh? Specifically in my case, I have a mattress that I have modelled for a bed, when I try to unwrap this the first problem that arises is the message that pops up in the info header,[image],
**first problem:**  what does the message mean?

The UV layout that I have created after hours of untangling, is(the green box here marks the area with the only pattern in the entire texture) :
[image],
**second problem:** was this a proper way to uv unwrap the mesh.

Furthermore, I had created an experimental texture in GIMP which I applied to the mesh:
[image: unwrapped image]
but the render turns out a bit stretched:
[image]
What are all these problems? How can I fix them? What is the correct way to uv unwrap and texture a subdivided mesh?

I have also included the file; with the texture packed:
[image]

Comment: The message simply means that the scale of your mesh is not 1 (or equal) in every direction. This can explain the stretch problem of the second question. So ctrl+A the scale to apply then scale (set it to 1) and unwrap again

Comment: scaling the mesh would distort it from the room scene though

Comment: no... you will keep the dimensions : apply the scale (don't modify it) : ctrl+A then scale. Do it on a copy if you are not confident... By the way : your blend file does not include the texture you want to match with. Can you upload again with the texture packed in it ?

Comment: How do I pack the file, I am working in cycles, I can't find the pack option.

Comment: If your object was scaled in object mode, the dimensions used for mapping will be inaccurate. Read the following links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320 **and** http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Comment: So initially the problem wouldn't have occured if I had scaled it in edit mode?

Comment: To pack textures within a file use File>External Data>Pack all into file, then save the file and re-upload

Comment: Scaling in edit mode will keep the scale of the object intact. If you scale in object mode you have to apply the transformations.

Comment: Yes... But scaling in object mode and applying scale is an usual way to do. About the packing : file menu/external data/auto pack into blend file

Comment: also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27113/unwrap-model-with-uvs-at-proper-size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is because the scales of your object are non uniform. That means that some axis has a different scale than the other (eg : (1, 2, 1)).

But, unwrap functions works on uniform scale. So, in order to keep the dimensions and unwrap with the good proportions, you need to apply the scale (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then '*scale*').

Here you can see the impact on the unwrapping :

[image]

By the way, it seems that your initial work on the UV map give few space for the main face of the mesh (it is in a small center part of the UVs).
You should unwrap the main faces as 'big surfaces' in order to have the best benefit of the texture.

Something like that, which is obtained automatically adding seams to each corner :

[image]

Comment: I would like the back part to not have a pattern and only the color of the texture, Is the unwrap that is not needed at the main visible part of the mesh always dumped aside as a seperate peice like I did above?

Comment: @bzal, in that case, select the UVs of this part which is just colored and scale it down. The other part can be scaled up (as more space is available for it). Some points in this recent question can interest you too : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61519/how-to-create-decal-from-mesh

Comment: How can I decrease the stretched look that has appeared at the rounded corners of the mattress? I tried editing the scale and location on the mapping node, but it didn't work.

Comment: @bzal, you can unwrap using "follow active quads", or, in the UV editor use "UVs to grid in respect to shape" which comes from an addon called "UV squares" (https://github.com/Radivarig/UvSquares)

Comment: I used the addon but the texture still look stretched at the rounded corners of the mesh. How can I fix that? I wonder if you have some spare time to upload the .blend.

Comment: @bzal, nothing is straight in the model, the model is 15.244x9.338 (ratio = 1.63), the texture is 4028x3000 but the part for the drawing is 1103x533 (ratio = 2.07). So I don't know what you mean by stretches ? The best you can obtain is unwrapping with the first unwrap option as it will maintain the ratio the best as possible. If you try to align the UVs you'll obtain stretches. Here is the file with a simple unwrap but considering the ratio stretch are unavoidable [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1834" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1834/)

Comment: the way you did it is awesome. But I have a question here, are every subsurfed objects uv unwrapped as so or is it just in the case of my model? If so do I need to remodel my mesh? (what are the numbers that are in your model when I TAB to edit mode? How do we toggle them?

Comment: @bzal, These numbers are the lengths of the edges (an option in the information panel N). Concerning the mesh, I think you needed to make it unstraight to compensate the subsurf. But you should add cuts to your mesh differently to avoid that. Have a try : add a plane, add 4 subsurf subdiv to it (don't apply), then cut it in edit mode ctrl+R. You'll see that restraints the subsurf effect at the corners, and also keep the mesh straight

Comment: that means the way I UV unwrapped was wrong, but wrong with respect to the geometry of my mesh. So, to compensate for that I need to add cuts to make the UV unwrap similar to that of my mesh?

Comment: That should be better to chat about that (but I do not know how to...). What I meant is that your base mesh IS distorded and that UV unwrap (first option) compensate that. Once done you can also check "use subsurf modifier" in the operator panel (it appear on the bottom left just after you validate the unwrapping). But even if all that can compensate, the first step stay the mesh geometry, I mean "by itself", because it seems you want straight things but what is modeled is not straight because subsurf is used with wrong/not enough cuts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44569/discussion-between-bzal-and-lemon).