# How do I unwrap this model for UV textures?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to unwrap part of the model you see below.

[image]

But whenever I press "Unwrap", it just gives an error message saying "Object has non-uniform scale, unwrap will operate on a non-scaled version of the mesh". Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: try selecting your mesh in object mode, and then press "Alt A" and then click "Apply scale"  this might fix it.

Comment: @ETHANDAY Doing that just started Animation Player. Is there something that causes that to happen?

Comment: It's CTRL-A in Object mode under 2.8/2.9 or Object menu > Apply.> Scale.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61527/how-to-effectively-uv-unwrap-a-subdivided-mesh/61532#61532