# UV mapping seems incorrectly distorted

Tags: uv

I'm very new to UV wrapping/unwrapping. However, I do understand the concept. I am trying to create a template to create the image I wish to apply to A curved surface on one side of a single object.

However, each time I true to use the Smart UV I get distorted results. I selected faces on the same side of a single curved surface but the UV wrap is more narrow than the object itself. I would expect the opposite.

Thanks!
[image: Distorted UV]

[image: actual object]

Comment: Was the object scaled in object mode? Did you apply scale before unwrapping?

Comment: for common questions use the search box on the top https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=uv+distorted

Comment: I'm sure it was scaled at one point. Does that mean in order to get a "clean" unwrapping, I can never scale my objects?

Comment: No, it means that you need to apply the scale before unwrapping. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27113/unwrap-model-with-uvs-at-proper-size/27118#27118